# Looking at results by group in multilevel structural equation model using lavaan

Tags: missing-data, multi-level, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm trying to do a multilevel structural equation model using a data set with observations from 32 different countries. I cluster the model by country. The model runs but on the output it says there were 29 clusters. Would there be a way to check which clusters are being dropped and where listwise deletion is removing cases?

```
fit.3b <- sem(mod3, data=data_merge, meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE, sampling.weights="WEIGHT", cluster = "country", optim.method = "em")
summary(fit.3b, fit.measures=TRUE, estimates=TRUE)
```

I was expecting there to be 32 clusters used in the output. I removed countries that were missing exogenous variables.

Comment: I removed an exogenous variable from the structural model and that got me up to 31 clusters. Any way to check what is the one cluster getting dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any fitted model, you can extract the vector of cluster IDs in that model:

```
library(lavaan)
example(Demo.twolevel)
lavInspect(fit, "cluster.id")
```

To extract the missing cluster(s), you could use `setdiff()` to compare that to the `unique()` values in your data's cluster-ID variable.

```
setdiff(unique(Demo.twolevel$cluster),   # what's in here...
        lavInspect(fit, "cluster.id"))   # but not in here?
```